# Efficient algorithm for computing angular velocity of a point cloud about a point

Tags: geometry, algorithms, point-cloud

Let's say I have a point cloud of $n$ points $P = \{p_1, p_2, \ldots, p_n\} \in \mathbb{R}^k$, where $k=2$ or $k=3$.  Further, we can assume that the points are on a rigid body, but with some small amount of noise.

I have the locations of the points along with the instantaneous velocity of each of the points.  However, I only have this one snapshot of the point cloud - I have no time series data.

Does there exist an efficient algorithm to extract the angular velocity of this point cloud?  For the 3D case ideally I would like to extract these in terms of Euler Angles if possible (but would settle for another representation).

Comment: If the points form a continuum, then the linear velocity is a vector field $\mathbb v(\mathbb x)$ on a subset of $\mathbb R^k$. The angular velocity bivector is proportional to the curl of this field: $$\Omega=\frac12\nabla\wedge\mathbb v.$$ And for a rigid body, $\mathbb v$ is a linear function of $\mathbb x$, so the derivatives in $\nabla$ can be replaced by finite differences. Now you just need a way to express $\nabla$ in terms of a $k$-dimensional mesh with vertices at $\{\mathbb p_1,\mathbb p_2,\cdots,\mathbb p_n\}$.

Comment: Alternatively, you could give each particle a mass $1$ and calculate the angular momentum $$L=\mathbb p_1\wedge\mathbb v_1+\mathbb p_2\wedge\mathbb v_2+\cdots+\mathbb p_n\wedge\mathbb v_n$$ and the rotational inertia tensor for variable $\Omega$, $$I(\Omega)=\mathbb p_1\wedge(\mathbb p_1\cdot\Omega)+\mathbb p_2\wedge(\mathbb p_2\cdot\Omega)+\cdots+\mathbb p_n\wedge(\mathbb p_n\cdot\Omega),$$ and then invert this linear transformation to get $\Omega=I^{-1}(L)$. (The dot and wedge products are those of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_algebra . Vector cross products may be used instead.)